# v-bind:value directive not working in Vuetify for v-switch inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, vuetify.js, vue-props

I have two way binding of property with `v-switch` input. I'm using `v-bind:value` as given

```html
<v-switch
  v-bind:input-value="tabs"
  label="Show Tabs"
  @change="(val) => $sync('tabs', !!val)"
/>
```

The issue is, when the value is supplied from the prop, sometimes switch renders according to the data supplied and sometimes not. `v-bind:input-value` does the job, but want to understand the underlying problem so that I can contribute to the library itself.

Comment: It happened to me too. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your switch needs a **reactive**, **mutable** ***Boolean*** in order to work properly.

If using setup

```
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue';

const myBoolean = ref( /* whatever determines Boolean */ );

</script>
```

Notice the `ref` wrapper.

Then whenever the condition inside ref changes your Vuetify switch will be updated.

```
<v-switch
  v-model="myBoolean"
  @change="/* whatever function changes Boolean */"
/>
```